# unmet dependencies apt

Tags: apt, dependencies

I am trying to install npm on Ubuntu 14.04. It says

```
npm : Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried all the solutions on the internet like

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install -f
apt-get clean
apt-get autoclean
apt-get autoremove
dpkg --configure -a
```

but still I am getting the same error.

When I tried `sudo aptitude install npm` and it says

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  build-essential{a} g++{a} g++-4.8{a} gyp{a} javascript-common{a} libc-ares-dev{a} libc-ares2{a} libc-dev-bin{ab} libc6-dev{ab} libjs-node-uuid{a} libssl-dev{a} 
  libstdc++-4.8-dev{a} libv8-3.14-dev{a} libv8-3.14.5{a} node-abbrev{a} node-ansi{a} node-archy{a} node-async{a} node-block-stream{a} node-combined-stream{a} 
  node-cookie-jar{a} node-delayed-stream{a} node-forever-agent{a} node-form-data{a} node-fstream{a} node-fstream-ignore{a} node-github-url-from-git{a} node-glob{a} 
  node-graceful-fs{a} node-gyp{a} node-inherits{a} node-ini{a} node-json-stringify-safe{a} node-lockfile{a} node-lru-cache{a} node-mime{a} node-minimatch{a} 
  node-mkdirp{a} node-mute-stream{a} node-node-uuid{a} node-nopt{a} node-normalize-package-data{a} node-npmlog{a} node-once{a} node-osenv{a} node-qs{a} 
  node-read{a} node-read-package-json{a} node-request{a} node-retry{a} node-rimraf{a} node-semver{a} node-sha{a} node-sigmund{a} node-slide{a} node-tar{a} 
  node-tunnel-agent{a} node-which{a} nodejs{a} nodejs-dev{a} npm zlib1g-dev{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 62 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
Need to get 25.7 MB of archives. After unpacking 73.8 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.20) but 2.24-17 is installed.
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.13) but 2.24-17 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)      build-essential [Not Installed]                    
2)      g++ [Not Installed]                                
3)      g++-4.8 [Not Installed]                            
4)      libc-dev-bin [Not Installed]                       
5)      libc6-dev [Not Installed]                          
6)      libssl-dev [Not Installed]                         
7)      libstdc++-4.8-dev [Not Installed]                  
8)      node-gyp [Not Installed]                           
9)      nodejs-dev [Not Installed]                         
10)     npm [Not Installed]                                
11)     zlib1g-dev [Not Installed]                         

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:         
12)     node-gyp recommends build-essential                


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?`<br/>
```

I dont understand what exactly is the problem. I also tried looking through the synaptic package manager and there is nothing reported in the Broken packages section.

Kindly advise.

Comment: The first error "libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.20) but 2.24-17 is installed" indicates that you have upgraded the c libraries from what is generally provided with Ubuntu 14.04 - what method did you use to do this?

Comment: It was a normal update....I did not do anything myself

Comment: Please append to your question the output of `apt show npm | grep Sources` and `apt show libc6 | grep Sources`

Comment: apt show npm | grep Sources
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface yet. Use with caution in scripts.
</br>
APT-Sources: http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
apt show libc6 | grep Sources

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface yet. Use with caution in scripts.

APT-Sources: /var/lib/dpkg/status
amit@amit-Lenovo-Z710:~$

Answer (score 2):

The NPM package that you are trying to install comes from the Ubuntu Trusty (14.04) archives, and requires a version of libc6 that is older than version 2.20.  The version of libc6 that is in the trusty archives is version 2.19 and would fit the bill.

Your system however has version 2.24-17 of libc6, and the source of that library is a .deb file which you presumably downloaded and installed because something that you wanted to run needed that newer version of libc6.  This is apparently from a Debian Wheezy package:  None of the Ubuntu archives have that particular library.  You can reference http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/ goes from 2.24-9 to 2.26-0 without the library in question.

So...

You have two choices, neither of which is going to be easy:

1. You can determine what package you downloaded from Debian and remove it, allowing your system to reinstall libc6 from the Ubuntu archives.  ***This may*** break some functionality that you have in your system.
2. You can look for a newer version of npm which will operate with libc6 2.24-17, and install that package ***which may*** install additional libraries which could break some functionality in your system.

Given the time frame of this question, installing npm does not seem to be of high importance to you.  My suggestion would be that you create a virtual machine if possible in your system.  Then you can install a version of linux on that machine and use that to load and run npm.

For future reference, although it is possible to load and install .deb packages intended for other distributions it is not always advisable.  These packages may have dependencies and libraries which conflict with the packages and libraries provided in Ubuntu.